# How to trigger Jenkins job by deploying git pipline using webhook?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I have a Jenkins job which I want to trigger after deploying pipeline in Gitlab, Is this possible with webhooks or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

I just played with it locally on a "safe network", but it may give you an idea.

I put in `.git/hooks/post-commit` something like:

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --http-user=$USER --http-password=$APITOKEN --secure-protocol=TLSv1 $JENKINS/job/$JOB/build?token=$JOBTOKEN -O /dev/null -o /dev/null
```

You need to create API token in jenkins and grab the webhook url for a given job.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [Generic Webhook Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger) plugin.

You can see a full example with complete Jenkins setup here: https://github.com/github/platform-samples/tree/master/hooks/jenkins/master-branch-protect